# Getting error in CardView when i use Parent Left and right

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I am new in android , getting error in CardView ,Logs are given below

ERROR LOG

```
Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'align_parentRight' in package 'android'

Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'align_parentLeft' in package 'android'

Error:(27) No resource identifier found for attribute 'align_toLeftOf' in package 'android'
```

Please any one help me how to resolve this issue ,i search in google but my problem was not solved please nay one help me

Here My XML code

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imag_bg"
            android:align_parentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


<TextView

    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#FF00FF"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:align_parentLeft="true"
        android:align_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
    android:id="@+id/text_View"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: Change the code to understand your problem please

Comment: I'm not sure this is right but try to use only android:layout_alignParentRight

Comment: i change my code have a look @FabioVenturiPastor

Comment: post screenshot of what you want or be clear

Comment: i up my post , i post image what i want ,please have a look @AmitVaghela

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35336294/2826147 answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer , as per your screenshot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nameDetailsBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/saveDeleteBar"
        android:layout_margin="10dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="3.25"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size_small"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textview3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:textColor="@color/darkslate"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgDoctorPresentation"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/presentation" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: con't resolve symbol style="@style/Widget.CardContent"@Amit Vaghela

Comment: it was style no need of that style for now

Comment: do you got the solution @chanti

Comment: in my image i need top and end space like above screen short@Amit Vaghela

Comment: add android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" to ImageView @chanti

Comment: make image size accordingly @chanti

Comment: thanq for ur answer @ Amit Vaghela

Comment: Glad that it helped @chanti

Comment: i am facing one problem in my first text i need two line but it show only single line text like above my screen short@Amit Vaghela

Comment: add this properties and check --- android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:singleLine="false"

Comment: you may need to change android:layout_weight accordingly beacuse it will cut the secondline of text @chanti

Comment: i changed that but my image was not visible please help me@Amit Vaghela

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the xml attributes `align_parentLeft`, `align_parentRight` and `align_toLeftOf` as this are unknown attributes

Also please explain further on what you want your layout to look like, your code seems confusing, your using too much alignParent attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `align_parentLeft` , `align_parentRight` and `align_toLeftOf` . These are invalid xml attributes. your working code is here .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imag_bg"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


        <TextView

            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FF00FF"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image_view"
            android:id="@+id/text_View"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Cheers ... Keep Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can also acheive this by using a Linear Layout and use weights, and use relative layout for your layout except imageView
below is the sample

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"

    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">


            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/text_View"
                android:layout_width="180dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FF00FF"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imag_bg"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```